# iOS Firebase: Sign in with SAML provider

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, saml

I am trying to setup my iOS app to sign in with a SAML provider by following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@tfalvo/single-sign-on-sso-for-your-firebase-app-with-saml-f67c71e0b4d6. At the end of the tutorial the author calls a sign in function in vanilla JS: `firebase.auth.SAMLAuthProvider('saml.jumpcloud-demo'); firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)`
Image of snippet: https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/0*2ZvQ_H2b10Ent9mb.

I cannot find the corresponding sign in with saml provider function in the Firebase Docs for Swift. Does anyone know how I would call a sign in with SAML in Swift?

If there isn’t an equivalent in the Firebase mobile app SDK is there another way I could implement this still within the app?

Comment: SAML auth is [not supported](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/662) in firebase for mobile apps. You may be able to use openid/oauth instead.

Comment: Could I somehow authenticate with SAML through a web view and pass the token back to the app?

Comment: Yes, you could do this.  I have seen this suggested as a solution in other posts on this issue.  You need to consider how you would get this token into the firebase framework if you wanted to use it with other firebase services like firestore